# IE and Edge fail to run Javascript for css change

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

I've made a simple script to change the color of a div with the class '.logged_inn_text'. The script works by taking the background style from the clicked link and inserting it to the class.

The code was made in Chrome and it worked perfectly fine, while in IE and Edge nothing happens. If I `alert` the var named color, there is no response. Is there a reasonable reason why it's not working?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.settings_color_btn').click(function() {
        var colorId = $(this).attr('id');
        var colorIdFull = '#'+colorId;
        var color = $(colorIdFull).css('background');
        $('.logged_inn_text').fadeTo('fast', 0.4, function() {
            $(this).css('background', color);
        }).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting really confused by reading that? When you click an element, you get the ID, then you use that ID as a selector, and you end up with .. the element that was just clicked, or in other words `this`? Anyway, assuming you're using a version of jQuery that works in the browsers you're using, there's no reason jQuery wouldn't work in IE.

Comment: Anyway, it works perfectly fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/kd4eqdvh/ I'm guessing you didn't give the element an ID

Comment: The `var color = $(colorIdFull).css('background');` will not give you a color, `var color = $(colorIdFull).css('backgroundColor');` should

Comment: @LGSon - correct, it gets you something like `rgb(255, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% ....` etc. and setting that value as the `background` style on another element should be valid as well.

Comment: @adeneo Yepp ... just wanted to point out that it is not only a color returned

Comment: @LGSon - And you're correct, seems IE returns `undefined` when trying to get the entire background style with jQuery, but `$(this).css('background-color')` actually works. Post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems IE return `undefined` (thanks to [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) who tested that), so changing

```
var color = $(colorIdFull).css('background');
```

to

```
var color = $(colorIdFull).css('background-color');
```

will do the trick